# Bootstrap4: Checkboxes and Labels Click Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap to design my forms. There is a checkbox and an associated label. My goal is to change the value of the checkbox by clicking on the checkbox and to be able to edit the text of the label by clicking on the label.
My problem now is that no matter which element I click on, whether label or checkbox, the same event is always called. However, I would like to separate these events.

I have tried it with different event handlers and I have also removed the for attribute.
I assume that the classes "custom-control-input" and "custom-control-label" are hindering me. But I want to keep the styling.

Can anyone tell me what else I can try? I would hate to write new styles and maintain them just because of this one use case.

// CLARIFICATION : I do not want to edit both controls at the same time. When I click on the checkbox, I want the checkbox value to toggle between true and false, and when I click on the label, I want to be able to edit the label text without affecting the checkbox value. So both elements work independently of each other.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.examples label').on('click', function(e) {
      debugger;
      console.log('Listener: Label Clicked');
    });
    $('.examples input').on('click', function(e) {
      console.log('Listener: CheckBox Clicked');
    });
  });

  function onClickLabel(e, label) {
    console.log('Label Clicked')
  }

  function onClickCheckBox(e, cb) {
    console.log('CheckBox Clicked')
  }
</script>

<div class="examples">


  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Does work, but ugly</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label class="" onClick="onClickLabel(event, this)">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Always triggers the checkbox</h3>
    <div>
      <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" class="" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label for="cb1" class="" onClick="onClickLabel(event, this)">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Triggers everything</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input id="cb0" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label for="cb0" class="custom-control-label" onClick="onClickLabel(event, this)">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Always triggers the label</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label class="custom-control-label" onClick="onClickLabel(event, this)">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you adding multiple events with the proper JavaScript but also `onClick="onClickLabel(event, this)`

Comment: Perhaps add the content editable given "edit the text of the label by clicking on the label"  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the label default and propagation then trigger the click using either the "for" attribute or a custom data attribute with a selector.  Examples:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.examples .editable-label').on('click', handleLabelClick);
  $('.examples .input[type="checkbox"].custom-control-input').on('click', handleCheckboxClick);
});

function handleLabelClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  this.focus();
  const forMe = '#' + $(this).attr("for");
  const target = $(this).data("target") && $(this).data("target").length ? $(this).data("target") : forMe;
  $(target).trigger('click');
}

function handleCheckboxClick(event) {
  console.log('CheckBox Clicked');
}
```

```css
.editable-label {
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="examples">
  <div class="mb-3 custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <h3>Does work, but ugly</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="ugly" id="ugly" />
      <label class="editable-label custom-control-label" for="ugly" contenteditable="true">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Always triggers the checkbox</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
      <label for="cb1" class="editable-label custom-control-label" contenteditable="true">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Triggers everything</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input id="cb0" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
      <label for="cb0" class="custom-control-label editable-label" contenteditable="true" data-target="#cb0">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Always triggers the label</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
      <label class="custom-control-label editable-label" contenteditable="true" data-target="#checkbox-3">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your answer, clicking on one of the controls triggers the label event, and then you change the value of the checkbox and edit the label manually. But I want the events/elements to be separate. Like the approach in 'Does work, but ugly'. Basically, I want the functionality from there, but using the look of the custom-control from bootstrap. But I think these classes are preventing me from achieving this. I think I need to copy the style.

Comment: Making labels for a form editable is a totally non-standard approach - the solution option to allow labels to be editable I present is ONE way to do that non-standard approach.  Similar a "shadow" input might be another - I think you need to consider how to clearly separate a view label from an editable entity - SO you either want the `label` editable or you DON"T; and live with that choice you as a functional designer have made.  FYIW Clicking a Label for a Checkbox to trigger the check/uncheck as I have here is the standard way labels work for those.

Comment: SO, what I am saying here is to STOP calling it a form checkbox label and perhaps make it a separate form control (as an input) - just my observation and suggestion.

Comment: As it stands, this gives you a checkbox and an editable "label" - which is what you asked for. Of course doing something with the edited label text was not part of the question and thus out of scope.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of misunderstanding here. The main problem is stated as "My problem now is that no matter which element I click on, whether label or checkbox, the same event is always called. However, I would like to separate these events.". And the title is about click events. So the text about the editable label has been included to help understand why I might want to split these events.
The code I have provided is an example of how I am trying to handle the click events. I was hoping for a hint on what else I could try to catch the correct events on click.

Answer (score 0):

By defining 'onClick="onClickLabel(event, this)"' you are creating an event, and at the same time you are creating the event in the html. Try removing onClick

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.examples label').on('click', function(e) {
      debugger;
      console.log('Listener: Label Clicked');
    });
    $('.examples input').on('click', function(e) {
      console.log('Listener: CheckBox Clicked');
    });
  });

  function onClickLabel(e, label) {
    console.log('Label Clicked')
  }

  function onClickCheckBox(e, cb) {
    console.log('CheckBox Clicked')
  }
</script>

<div class="examples">


  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Does work, but ugly</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label class="">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Always triggers the checkbox</h3>
    <div>
      <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" class="" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label for="cb1" class="">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Triggers everything</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input id="cb0" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <label for="cb0" class="custom-control-label">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <h3>Always triggers the label</h3>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onClick="onClickCheckBox(event, this)">
      <label class="custom-control-label">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the example under the heading 'Does work, but ugly' fulfils the desired functionality. Even with my original code. But it doesn't work when I use the custom control classes from bootstrap. I don't think I understand your answer, because as far as I can see the problem still exists.